# Why is border-radius making my browser lag when scrolling div contents?

Tags: css, lag

I have a fixed position div with CSS styles applied to it via a class. The class looks like this:

```
.DataBox {
    background-color:rgba(200,200,200,0.2);
    /* border-radius:32px; Seems to make things super laggy... */
    border-color:#606060;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;/**/
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color:#606060;
    display:none;
    left:0px;
    margin:0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    padding:16px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
```

Everything works fine when I comment out `border-radius`, but I would love a round rect for the style of my div. Now, keep in mind that the rest of the CSS works fine with no lag at all when I comment out `border-radius`, so I know that that is the problem. The `display:none` is changed in JavaScript, so don't pay any attention to that.

Does anyone know why the round rect is a problem? Does it have something to do with how it culls elements inside the div when they begin to overlap the rounded corners? I am hoping there's a way to work around this without cheap hacks like a second styled div on top of my actual div... The contents of the div, by the way, are just a few `<p>` elements.

Thanks for your help!

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the bare minimum of the problem code. You won't really be able to see the lag on a desktop/laptop. My main problem is with mobile devices... If you actually take the time to view the fiddle on a mobile device, zoom in on the output pane, because it's kind of hard to tell it's lagging, but it definitely lags. https://jsfiddle.net/oL1fh65a/1/

Comment: I think `border-radius` is known to cause performance issues when it is used on elements with a lot of child elements.

Comment: I read that, too, but I only have a small `<h1>` and a `<p>` with like three hundred characters.

Comment: can you add a fiddle with this issue?

Comment: I added a link to the fiddle, but the problem is really only visible on my phone, which I'm using for testing. It's a Moto G and I'm experiencing the lag in all of the android mobile browsers. i.e. Chrome, Firefox, Opera for android.

Comment: @Frank native android browser? os version?

Comment: It's just chrome for Android. Visit the link in your phone, I'm sure you'll see what I mean. I'm certain it has something to do with culling the contents of the div underneath the rounded edge. It must be somewhat more complicated than simple rectangular culling, but I can't believe it would be that much slower...

Comment: i try it on my Nexus 5 Chrome browser, and all is ok, can't find any problem

Comment: I can confirm I get similar results. Tested on android devices and Chrome browser version: HTC E9 / Nexus 4 - Version 48.0.2564.95